# Float <td> in HTML

Tags: html, html-table

I use `float: left; width: 100%;` on `<td>`s on a breakpoint to linearize a two column layout in mobile. This works, and I haven't seen any reason to do otherwise. I have also had success putting the `float`/`width` on tables within the `<td>` and setting `width: 100%; display: block;` on the `<td>`. Both work, but the second seems like more effort for the same effect. Is there a better technique I could be using? I'm just looking for some feedback and experiences from other developers.

Comment: It sounds like you are confusing TDs with DIVs.  You can't float a TD.

Comment: @durbnpoisn - I you play with `display` you can do many things.

Comment: FWIW, if you assign anything `display:block;`, it automatically gets `width:100%;`

Comment: No, not confusing TD with DIV. I'm actually applying the float on the breakpoint which is working across devices/clients.Also, good call @RyanB.